# ASP.NET Ajax Serialize Form and pass other parameters to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I would like to send more than just the serialized form data to the controller. for example I'd like to include other parameters. Something like:

```
    data: {record:formData, searchLetter:letter, page:pageNum}
```

However, whenever I try this, the model does not properly bind, it ends up being null.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.save-attendance-record-button').click(function() {

        $('#form-edit-attendance-record').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;

        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'html',
            method: 'post',
            url: resolveUrl('~/Home/EditAttendanceRecord'),
            data: { record:formData, searchLetter:"a", searchTerm:"", page:1 }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#attendance-records-partial').html(data);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#form-edit-attendance-record').submit();  
});
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditAttendanceRecord(AttendanceRecord record, string searchLetter, int? page)
{
     //...
}
```

**Edit 1**

Here is what formData looks like when it is the only argument:

```
ID=2&InviteeFirstName=Test%20K.&InviteeLastName=Test&InviteeCheckedIn=true&InviteeCheckedIn=false&GuestName=test&GuestCheckedIn=true&GuestCheckedIn=false&RSVP=
```

If I have multiple parameters (which is what i want) the request header looks like this:

```
record=ID%3D2%26InviteeFirstName%3DTest%2520K.%26InviteeLastName%3DTest%26InviteeCheckedIn%3Dfalse%26GuestName%3DWOW%26GuestCheckedIn%3Dtrue%26GuestCheckedIn%3Dfalse%26RSVP%3D&searchLetter=a&searchTerm=&page=1
```

or parsed:

```
record:ID%3D2%26InviteeFirstName%3DTest%2520K.%26InviteeLastName%3DTest%26InviteeCheckedIn%3Dfalse%26GuestName%3DWOW%26GuestCheckedIn%3Dtrue%26GuestCheckedIn%3Dfalse%26RSVP%3D 
searchLetter:a 
searchTerm: 
page:1
```

Comment: Is this the code for your attempt to send all 3 arguments, or just the serialized form data?  If the latter, please show us your attempt to send all 3.

Comment: @Jakotheshadows whoops. Okay, I've edited it. just changed the data: arugment

Comment: What's the reason for `dataType: 'html'` ?

Comment: @JesseJohnson I return a partialview aka html from my controller, so I am specifying the dataType of what I return to be HTML.

Comment: Gotcha. Are you able to set a breakpoint and check the value of `formData`?

Comment: @JesseJohnson I edited my post to show the request values